# visual studio 2010 static code analysis migration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, policy, static-code-analysis, checkin

I am updating my projects from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010, but I'm still using TFS 2008.

I have a static code analysis in my TFS, and when I was using visual studio 2008 I was placing the rules from the server in my source code projects (right click on a solution->Code analysis for solution-> replace\merge with checkin policy)

When I upgraded to VS 2010, new ruleset files where generated, with different rules from those I had in VS2008. Plus, I can't find the "replace\merge with checkin policy" option.

How can I apply static code analysis in VS 2010 & TFS 2010?